# Парсинг QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt

Есть контейнер, содержащий последовательность байт:

```
QByteArray array("ffeeddccbbaa99");
```

По нему можно перемещаться поэлементно, используя методы `.at(i)`, `indexOf()` и т. д., но тогда `array.at(0)`  вернёт `"f"`, а хотелось бы получить `"ff" (quint8*)`. У меня есть несколько мыслей, к примеру привести `byteArray` к `stringList`, и сплитить через `regExp` по 2 элемента, но это совсем не умно…

Возможно кто-нибудь знает как это сделать средствами самого `QByteArray`? Буду признателен за любой совет.

Comment: посмотрите на метод fromHex (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#fromHex). Данный метод за вас декодирует исходную последовательно 16-ричного представления в массив байтов, а дальше вы уже можете работать с байтами как с байтами

Comment: @goldstar_labs, спасибо, именно то что нужно!

Comment: @goldstar_labs, можете оформить как ответ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ товарища @goldstar_labs решил мою проблему:

> Посмотрите на метод fromHex (doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#fromHex).
>   Данный метод за вас декодирует исходную последовательно 16-ричного
>   представления в массив байтов, а дальше вы уже можете работать с
>   байтами как с байтами

Comment: товарищи! я был рад оказать посильную помощь товарищу!